# Pytorch Multiclass Logistic Regression Type Errors

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

I'm new to ML and even more naive with Pytorch. Here's the problem. (I've skipped certain parts like the random_split() which seem to work just fine)

I've to predict wine quality (red) which from the dataset is the last column with 6 classes

[That's what my dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NuSR.png)

[The link to the dataset (winequality-red.csv)](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/)

```
features = df.drop(['quality'], axis = 1)
targets = df.iloc[:, -1] # theres 6 classes

dataset = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.array(features)).float(), torch.Tensor(targets).float())
# here's where I think the error might be, but I might be wrong

batch_size = 8
# Dataloader

train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle = True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size)
test_ds = DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size)

input_size = len(df.columns) - 1
output_size = 6
threshold = .5

class WineModel(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

  def forward(self, xb):
    out = self.linear(xb)
    return out

model = WineModel()
n_iters = 2000
num_epochs = n_iters / (len(train_ds) / batch_size)
num_epochs = int(num_epochs)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)

# the part below returns the error on running
iter = 0 
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(x)
    loss = criterion(outputs, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

**RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float**

Hopefully that is sufficient info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The targets for [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) are given as the class indices, which are required to be integers, to be precise they need to be of type `torch.long`, which is equivalent to `torch.int64`.

You converted the targets to floats, but you should convert them to longs:

```py
dataset = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.array(features)).float(), torch.Tensor(targets).long())
```

Since the targets are the indices of the classes, they must be in range *[0, num_classes - 1]*. As you have 6 classes that would be in range [0, 5]. Having a quick look at your data, the quality uses values in range [3, 8]. Even though you have 6 classes, the values cannot be used directly as the classes. If you list the classes as `classes = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, you can see that the first class is 3, `classes[0] == 3`, up to the last class being `classes[5] == 8`.

You need to replace the class values with the indices, just like you would for named classes (e.g. if you had the classes *dog* and *cat*, *dog* would be 0 and *cat* would be 1), but you can avoid having to look them up, since the values are simply shifted by 3, i.e. `index = classes[index] - 3`. Therefore you can subtract 3 from the entire target tensor:

```py
torch.Tensor(targets).long() - 3
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! That worked. What's the reason as to why the classes are to be imputed like that and converted to long() ? Rather than Pytorch just figuring it out

Comment: They need to be indices, because PyTorch has no way of knowing what your possible classes are. How would it know that 3 is your first class, especially since a batch does not always contain all possible classes. That literally tells PyTorch how to index the output of the model. Indexing can only be done with integers, floats are not allowed, even pure Python disallows it (e.g. `some_list[3.0]`), and PyTorch doesn't automatically convert them to long because that would lose information (rounds them down) `torch.tensor(3.7).long() == 3` and possibly hide a bug, such as passing the wrong tensor.